# Motion interpolation - 120 hz monitor effect

Tags: video, effects

I have a normal 60hz monitor (http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/reviews/benq_gw2760hs.htm) but I also have a 120hz Samsung TV and I have seen the `Motion Plus` effect that makes movies play very smooth and clear, especially during action scenes.

Now, is there a way to reproduce a similar effect on Ubuntu with any player?

For instance I found [this](http://www.tested.com/tech/pcs/329-how-to-enable-motion-interpolation-on-your-movie-files/) but it's for Windows computers and I don't know if that works.

I usually use `VLC`, `Smplayer` with `mpv` or `mplayer`.
Any way to make them do something like that?

Thanks